# What is the meaning of error ActiveContractNotFound - Amazon Gift Card On Demand (AGCOD)

Tags: amazon-product-api

Our backend has been using the AGCOD api for a while and hasn't had any problem creating gift cards.
However, although we haven't made code change, we started to see this error to every single request to POST /CreateGiftCard:

```
No active valid contract was found. Customer does not have access to CreateGC
```

I've searched here and there but it seems like the best description of the error is the following :

```
ActiveContractNotFound
ErrorCode -- F300
ErrorType – ActiveContractNotFound
Message – Active Contract Not Found
Mock Error Request ID – F3009
```

- source: http://s3.amazonaws.com/AGCOD/tech_spec/AGCODTechSpec_WC-FAQ-Appendix_EN.pdf

Can anyone provide the meaning to this error or at least a link to more detailed documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's exactly what they mean - "Active Contract Not Found". Your contract with Amazon expired or got cancelled. So they do not allow you to create the gift cards anymore.

Talk with their Incentives support team and review what's going on.

Comment: That's what I figured too but I couldn't find the right contact. But I now I found it and has reached out to them providing my partnerId.

However I'm not sure if they'd respond back since according to the linked document (section: "Contacting Amazon for Technical Support"), they require the contract to still be active to entertain support emails :/

Comment: I contacted their incentives support team using the email provided in the document and they got back to within an hour with a resolution. It turned out the contract was deactivated (by mistake) and they have reactivated it again :D

Comment: This is a nice resolution, though not nice that the mistake happened. Glad it was resolved, though :)